# select best maven strategy for create multi module

Tags: java, maven

We have a project structure like this

[image: project structure]

As you see we have following projects :

1. Core Project
2. Project A
3. Project A Customization For Compant C
4. Project A Customization For Company D
5. Project B
6. Project B Customization For Company C
7. Project B Customization For Company D
8. Company A Project
9. Company B Project

In the know we use ANT and we will switch to MAVEN. I have been confused for selecting best strategy for MAVEN POM. In the first i thought, we can use inheritance for project 1..7 and projects 8 and 9 can be multi module project. 
In the know i have a several question:

- Is there any better solution for this purpose?
- all projects are web-project and consists web pages and resources. and each other has many files (thousands files in each project) so packing waste many time. is there any way that maven prevents packaging goal? (We do not want any projects to be packed jar or war).
- Furthermore projects 8 and 9 can have their sources in addition to projects they contains. can a multi module project has any source for itself?

I know my questions may seems stupid but im new in MAVEN. so i would like, you give me a full described answer. Thanks alot.

Comment: What do you mean by "project inheritance"?

Comment: @JFMeier for example in above diagram when i say project A inherited from Core Project, it means Project A use Core Project as dependency

Comment: Ok, and I furthermore don't understand how you want to use projects if you do not package them as jar or war?

Comment: @JFMeier if you talk about leaf projects so web servers like tomcat can accept unpacked projects.

Comment: What kind of customization do you need? Only configuration or code changes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

A parent pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
  <artifactId>abcd-parent-example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>abcd-parent-example</name>

  <modules>
    <module>web-a</module>
    <module>web-b</module>
    <module>web-a-for-c</module>
    <module>core</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

A core project which is a jar

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <artifactId>abcd-parent-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>core</artifactId>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

A default web-a project which has a dependency on core

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <artifactId>abcd-parent-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>web-a</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>web-a</finalName>
  </build>

</project>
```

A customized web-a-for-c which uses [maven overlays](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) for customize the default web-a

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <artifactId>abcd-parent-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>web-a-for-c</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
      <artifactId>web-a</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <overlays>
                        <overlay>
                            <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
                            <artifactId>web-a</artifactId>
                        </overlay>
                </overlays>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Here's some help creating the projects with maven archetypes:

First create a parent

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=pom-root -DarchetypeVersion=RELEASE
```

Then cd to the parent, the create a basic core jar

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart
```

Then create a basic web project

```
mvn archeype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

Comment: i think overlay can be good idea. i need have a study about it. but in the now i have a question. in production environment i have just a project (company a or b project) that contains customized version of a or b plus core projects. it means for example in tomcat web app i most have just a one project. can this model support my need? will i have a overlayed project if i run `mvn install`  on on `abcd-parent-example` or in another form multi module pom can support overlay or it just run mvn command on each included project?

Comment: @RasoulTaheri the example I've given you will build all the projects in the parent, the core project will make a jar, the web projects will make complete wars suitable for Tomcat, web-a will be a war, web-a-for-c will be a war with the bits replaced in web-a by whatever you have in web-a-for-c.